# Area between two probability density functions as distance measure

Tags: density-function, distance

I have two distinct probability density functions, and I would like to find a synthetic measure of how different the two distributions are. Intuitively, it would make sense to me to compute the area between the two curves, as in the example shown below[image]

Source: [How to visualise the difference between probability distribution functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377437/how-to-visualise-the-difference-between-probability-distribution-functions)

The metric would range between 0 (perfect overlapping) and 2 (no overlapping), and would be computed as the integral of the absolute value of the difference between the two PDFs.
However, after searching the internet for a similar metric, I wasn't able to find any. What is the downside of such an apparently simple metric? Am I getting something wrong?

Edit: Image is for visualization purposes only. It is not mine and I am not trying to compare two samples (rather, two known PDFs).

A reference to a similar metric is made in [this paper, see equation 2](https://lilia.dpss.psy.unipd.it/%7Emassimiliano.pastore/papers/Pastore&Calcagni_2019.pdf), but other than this I can't find anything close to it. Something close to what I mean, albeit for discrete distributions, is the dissimilarity index.

Does my proposed metric not make sense? I am asking this question because it seems one of the most intuitive ways to gauge the difference between two PDFs, yet I can find virtually no reference to it on the web.

Comment: did you look at Kolmogorov-smirnov metric? it's the max distance between CDFs

Comment: @Aksakal Yes, I know about the KS test but it's not really what I was looking for. I have found a paper that mentions something similar to my idea (https://lilia.dpss.psy.unipd.it/~massimiliano.pastore/papers/Pastore&Calcagni_2019.pdf). It links the non-overlapping area between two PDFs to the KL divergence, but I can't quite see how.

Comment: Easier to deal with cdf

Comment: Since, in a sense, the CDF **is** the area of a PDF, and since the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic $D$ measures the difference of greatest magnitude between two CDFs, it is difficult for me to understand why the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic does not meet your needs, as @Aksakal mentioned.

Comment: Because you complain that a well-known, general, theoretically understood metric is "not ... what I was looking for," you ought to edit your post to indicate more clearly what it is you *are* looking for.  It is puzzling, too, that your graphics indicate you are working with *samples.*  How, then, do you obtain *densities?*  This detail might matter.  If your objective is to compare *samples,* then why run your analysis through this intermediate step of estimating a density when you could compare the samples directly?

Comment: @whuber observation on samples makes cdf even more convenient: empirical cdf is much more accurate than empirical pdf

Comment: @whuber thank you for your comment. The image I attached is only meant to offer a visualization of the quantity I am interested in, i.e. the area between the two PDFs. My post asked whether a metric of that kind exists / is useful in order to compare two known PDFs. I am asking this question because it seems one of the most intuitive distance measures, yet I couldn't find any reference to methods of this kind on the web (apart from a brief reference here: https://lilia.dpss.psy.unipd.it/~massimiliano.pastore/papers/Pastore&Calcagni_2019.pdf). Any ideas why? Does that metric not make sense?

Comment: It's not very general, because many common, useful distributions do not have densities.  Regardless, there are *many* metrics.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=pdf+overlap for instance.  But any $L^p$ metric will work, too, as well as any metric that compares the distributions themselves (KS, Wasserman, KD, etc).  The real issue comes down to choosing among such a huge variety of metrics to meet your statistical needs, whatever they might be.

Comment: In 1D, the integral of the absolute value of the differences in two CDFs gives you the 1-Wasserstein distance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric#One-dimensional_distributions

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271582/is-the-intersection-area-between-2-pdfs-a-probability/271590#271590